# How do I configure sites.php for a multi-site with fixed IP and subdir?

Tags: multi-sites

I have just installed clean minimal Drupal 9, created a `sites/sites.php` with the following line

```php
$sites['10.0.0.133.drupal.web.foo-bar'] = 'foo-bar.com';
```

and the following subdir `sites/foo-bar.com` with `settings.php` that includes the correct database settings. After entering `http://10.0.0.133/drupal/web/foo-bar` into the browser, the `default` site respond which means the site alias has not been recognized.

Any idea? Do I need a web server vhost created for each site?

Answer (score 0):

After some trying I've found that there HAS to be a web server virtual host pointing at the root drupal directory

Comment: That is documented in `sites.php`.